# Angular custom library has HTTP dependency - inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-library

I have an Angular 8 app that consumes a Service from a custom library I created.

The Service makes a HTTP call, so it has a dependency for an instance of the HttpClient in its constructor as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { GetLoggedInUserInfo } from '../../models/get-logged-in-user-info';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getLoggedInUser = ({
    apiUrl,
    apiContextRoot,
  }: GetLoggedInUserInfo): Observable<User> => {
      const url = `${apiUrl}${apiContextRoot}/login`;

      return this.http.get<User>(url).pipe(
      );
    }
  };
}
```

The problem occurs when I invoke the getLoggedInUser() method of this service from the client app that custom installed the library via "npm install".

It seems that the dependency is not being fulfilled for the service in the custom library, which I thought would occur automatically.

```
main.ts:12 Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:728)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:744)
    at AuthService_Factory (gulfstream-common.js:493)
    at _callFactory (core.js:30485)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:30428)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30387)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31577)
    at resolveDep (core.js:32142)
    at createClass (core.js:31988)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:31806)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a way how your `AuthService` is used?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813 seems like the same issue like yours

Comment: The AuthService just makes an Http call to a Node.js back-end service that queries the database and returns a row of data for a particular user.   Because that functionality is needed in every app that's created, I thought it best to put it in a Library that can be easily reused.

Answer (score 3):

@Andrei provided the link github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813, which helped to resolve the issue.

I updated the angular.json file, of the app that consumes the library, and included **"preserveSymlinks": true** in 2 locations:

1. under "architect"->"build"->"options"
2. for each configuration under "architect"->"build"->"configurations"

Thanks

Comment: This fixed my issues when trying to use libraries locally with npm link.